# React: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop when Mapping custom components

Tags: reactjs, key, mapping

I have a custom material-ui component as defined below.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Paper from 'material-ui/lib/paper';

function PaperBox (props) {
  return (
    <Paper className={props.layout}>
      <div className="row center-xs">
        <p>{props.box.title}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="row center-xs">
        <p className="col-xs-10">
          {props.box.text}
        </p>
      </div>
    </Paper>
  );
}

PaperBox.propTypes = {
  box: PropTypes.shape({
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.any.isRequired
  }).isRequired,

  layout: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default PaperBox;
```

And in another file I have a parent component that maps an array of text objects to the above-mentioned component as shown below

```
import React from 'react';
import PaperBox from '../shared/PaperBox/PaperBox';

const layout = 'col-md-3 col-xs-8';

function DetailContent (props) {
  return (
    <div className="row around-xs">
      {props.boxes.map(box => <PaperBox key={box.title} box={box} layout={layout} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default DetailContent;
```

As you can imagine, "props.boxes" is an array of text objects

```
const boxes = [
  {
    title: 'one',
    text: 'I am a bunch of text'
  },
  {
    title: 'two',
    text: 'I am also a bunch of text'
  },
];
```

What is very bizarre to me is that though I added key attribute to the **PaperBox** component, it still prints *Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.* in the console. Is there a solution to this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is the title guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782782/react-unique-key-prop

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh, I changed the key to iterator index but the error still persists

Comment: @Theo the OP there experiences a very similar problem as I do but I do not have any iterator in my custom child component.

Comment: Here is the original repo: https://github.com/lorix-lpan/perfect-schedule, hope this will help to figure out the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the array index as the unique key for each child:

```
props.boxes.map((box, i) => <PaperBox key={i} box={box} layout={layout} />)
```

Comment: It still prints the same error message: *'Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. 'Check the render method of `PaperBox`'*. One thing I found very interesting is that when I remove the "key" attribute in DetailContent.jsx, it prints one additional error: *'Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `DetailContent`'*. Maybe the issue lies within the custom child component being created dynamically? (in this case is PaperBox)